# Configuring RunTimeException class in Struts2

Tags: struts2, runtimeexception

My requirement is as follows. My application is built on Struts2 framework and using annotation plugin. When I get any `RunTimeException` I need to call a method of my custom class which prints error stack using `e.printStackTrace()` method. How can I configure this class in my application. I do not want to use try and catch block in each and every actions I have.

After getting error I want to display `error.jsp` to user. but in my tomcat console I would like to print error stack. Please let me know if anyone is having idea.

Thanks
Peter

Comment: are you using spring framework in your development.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about annotation since  i have used it very limited but it can be done easily using struts.xml file with the help of `ExceptionMappingInterceptor`.

All you need to define custom stack for this and add few parameter to the xml file to let S2 handle the uncaught exception and at same time log that in the log file/console

```
<interceptors>
  <interceptor-stack name="appDefaultStack">
    <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack">
     <param name="exception.logEnabled">true</param>
     <param name="exception.logLevel">ERROR</param>
    </interceptor-ref>
 </interceptor-stack>
</interceptors>

<default-interceptor-ref name="appDefaultStack" />
```

For more details refer to [exception-handling](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1/docs/exception-handling.html). I believe it can be easily converted to annotation based solution as annotation plugin provides all options what can be done in XML file.